# How to drag and drop a line segment (fragment only) in kinetic JS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

There is a tut on line drag and drop here :
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-a-line-with-kineticjs/

But more interestingly how to do drag and drop a line segment (fragment only) in kinetic JS ?
There's no example for doing this.

**In my use case the segment stays attached to polyline, it just changes angle.** so I don't want to create another polyline with one segment only which would also be a waste of resource.

Answer (score 0):

**How to drag one segment of a polyline with the other segments remaining connected**

You can create a series of 2-point kinetic.lines (just a start and end point).

Each new start point is the end point of the previous line

This screenshot shows the green segment being dragged and the other segments changing accordingly.

**Result: A polyline made up of draggable segments.**

[image][image]

Note: after any segment is dragged, the getX()/getY() contain the distance dragged from its original XY.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GrEEL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width:300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var colors=['red','green','blue','orange'];

    var lines=[];

    var points=[];
    points.push({x:125,y:50});
    points.push({x:75,y:75});
    points.push({x:200,y:200});
    points.push({x:275,y:100});

    for(var i=0;i<points.length-1;i++){
        var p1=points[i];
        var p2=points[i+1];
        addSegment(i,p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y,colors[i]);
    }

    layer.draw();


    function addSegment(i,x1,y1,x2,y2,color){

        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
            points: [x1,y1,x2,y2],
            stroke:color,
            strokeWidth: 25,
            lineCap:"round",
            lineJoin:"round",
            draggable:true
        });
        line.index=i;
        line.on("dragend",function(){

            // get the amount of xy drag
            var i=this.index;
            var dx=this.getX();
            var dy=this.getY();

            // update the points array
            var p0=points[i];
            var p1=points[i+1];
            p0.x+=dx;
            p0.y+=dy;
            p1.x+=dx;
            p1.y+=dy;

            // reset the dragged line
            this.setPosition(0,0);
            this.setPoints([p0.x,p0.y,p1.x,p1.y]);

            layer.draw();
        });
        line.on("dragmove",function(){

            // get the amount of xy drag
            var i=this.index;
            var dx=this.getX();
            var dy=this.getY();

            // adjust the ending position of the previous line
            if(i>0){
                var line=lines[i-1];
                var pts=line.getPoints();
                pts[1].x=points[i].x+dx;
                pts[1].y=points[i].y+dy;
                line.setPoints(pts);
            }

            // adjust the starting position of the next line
            if(i<lines.length-1){
                var line=lines[i+1];
                var pts=line.getPoints();
                pts[0].x=points[i+1].x+dx;
                pts[0].y=points[i+1].y+dy;
                line.setPoints(pts);
            }

            layer.draw();
        });
        layer.add(line);
        lines.push(line);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see...keep the polyline connected---allow any segment to be dragged with the polyline conforming to the dragged segment.  See the addition to by answer.